# Playing video in html5 player in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, html, video

I play mp4 format video from FTP Server using html5 video tag in asp.net.
FTP server link is changed by using HFS http File Server.Video is playing well and everything is ok.but if i play a video in a browser then same video can not play in other computer or other browser in same computer.. What is the problem ???? Is the problem is for FTP ??? Help me to solve this problem

**HTML CODE:**

```
<video id="loadVideoSource" runat="server" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-tech" controls="controls" preload="auto" width="640" height="500" data-setup="{}" type="video/mp4" />
```

**ASPX.CS**

```
 loadVideoSource.Src = Url;
```

Also can not download same file when it's Playing

Comment: can you show your code

Comment: Html Code ==>><video id="loadVideoSource" runat="server" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-tech" controls="controls" preload="auto" width="640" height="500" data-setup="{}" type="video/mp4" />

Comment: Aspx.cs Code= >> on page load  loadVideoSource.Src = Url;

Comment: value of Url comes From database.

Comment: please give an example of what Url looks like when you set the source... is it a path that the browser can see?

Comment: http://localhost/Movie/12.mp4

actually i think this problem is for HFS http file server. this software do not give access get same file at same time... I think i have to solve this problem. if you have any idea please help